# Как возвращаемое значение из функции сделать constexpr

Tags: c++, constexpr

Есть код

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

  constexpr int get_mode(int mode_t)
  {
    return mode_t;
  }
   void SetMode(int mode_t)
  {
    constexpr int  m = get_mode(mode_t);
  }

int main()
{

    SetMode(1);
}
```

Нужно m сделать constexpr, почему компилятор ругается на mode_t, говорит что не константное выражение.
И вообще так можно делать?

[Онлайн компилятор](https://godbolt.org/z/3mafA_)

Comment: У вас `SetMode` обычная функция. И как в ней будет `constexpr` переменная, которая должна быть вычислена во время компиляции, если неизвестно, что вы ей передадите во время выполнения?... Ведь ваша `m` должна быть вычислена один раз, во время компиляции, и не зависеть от `mode_t`...

Comment: Вот так - `void SetMode(int mode_t)
{
    constexpr int  m = get_mode(1);
}` - запросто. Ведь во время компиляции неизвестно, что попадет в `SetMode`.

Comment: Тут можно попробовать переделать аргумент в параметр шаблона.